# Does anyone know why the styling on my bootstrap themed portfolio got messed up when I deployed it to heroku?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

Portfolio page: https://rookiefolio2.herokuapp.com/

Github repo: https://github.com/dalabi/rookiefolio

Comment: Check the console log, you're getting 403 for bootstrap.min.css among other errors.

Answer (score 0):

**While I have checked your document I have found you are misspelled with these four files.**

Do one thing,replace the directory with appropriate files of

1. Bootstrap.min.css
2. Fontawesome.min.css
3. Jquery.min.js
4. Bootstrap.min.js

or, Rewrite your code by putting these files on Header of your document

```
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I actually got it to work because I decided to use node with an accompanying server file. I'm going to try this out to see if it works with php